# Give access to specific Active Directory Groups and local users

Tags: ssh, authentication, active-directory

I have a server which is connected to the active directory, everything works fine (at least I guess) and everyone can access the server with their AD credentials, but I wan only specific group to be able to access the server, I made some changes in `/etc/security/access.conf` and added the following line  `+:@MY-GROUP :ALL`, and also uncommented the line `-:ALL:ALL`, but no one is able to login even the local account on the server and I get the error: `Connectin closed by Server-IP port SSH-Port`, and when I change the line to `+:@MY-GROUP ALL:ALL`, everyone can access the server

Comment: As the man page for `access.conf` says, the sign `@` in this file is used to indicate **netgroups**, which are used by NIS. This is something very different from a "regular" users group in the system. According to the same man page, names of groups should be written in parentheses: `(group)`. Try this.